# how to concatenate sql query in newline in vb6.0?

Tags: mysql, vb6

i want to concatenate sql query that is not in single line but new line .

```
Conn.Execute "insert into users("
"FirstName,"
"LastName,"
"Address1,"
"Address2,"
")values("
" UCase(txtfirstname.Text) &" ,
"& UCase(txtlastname.Text) &",
" & UCase(txtaddress1.Text) & ",
" & UCase(txtaddress2.Text) & "
")"
```

how to concatenate them into single one?

Thanks ,
Yugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VB6 to do a line continuation you end a line with [space][underscore].  You also need to use the & to concatenate the text segments on each line together. So the line would look something like this:

```
Conn.Execute "insert into users(" _
& "FirstName," _
& "LastName," _
& "Address1," _
& "Address2" _
& ")values(" _
& UCase(txtfirstname.Text) & "," _
& UCase(txtlastname.Text) & "," _
& UCase(txtaddress1.Text) & "," _
& UCase(txtaddress2.Text) _
& ")"
```

Comment: You also had an extra comma AFTER address2 two that was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Conn.Execute "insert into users(FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2) values('" & UCase(txtfirstname.Text) & "', '" & UCase(txtlastname.Text) & "', '" & UCase(txtaddress1.Text) & "', '" & UCase(txtaddress2.Text) & "'")"
```